# Power shell поиск Employee ID по фильтру ENDS WITH

Tags: powershell

надо сделать скрипт в Powershell чтобы искал в Active Directory ID работников по аналогии с фильтром AD "ends with".
скрипт сделал, но он ищет только конкретное Employee ID (т.е. равное тому что вводишь). 
Как сделать чтобы был поиск типа филтра "заканчивается на.." (ends with)?
например, ID работника 345678, надо чтобы искались все комбинации типа _345678, 012345678, и т.д.
Спасибо.

Comment: скрипт выложите

Comment: или попробуйте, что-то типа    'Get-ADUser -Filter 'employeeid -like "*345678" -Properties employeeid' то бишь, поставить символ подстановки *

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeID -like '*345678'}
```